# How to decrypt Android JSON payload?

Tags: java, android, encryption

I am new to Android and java in general, i wanted to inspect how a specific app works, so i begun by de-compiling the app using `apktool` and then used `jadx` to browse the source files, everything makes sense so far, so i added a `mitmproxy` to inspect the network traffic from the app.

I know that the request reply is a JSON payload, however "some of them" are encrypted possibly using `mcrypt` or `openssl`? so tracing methods leads me to this file.

```java
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class MC {
    private IvParameterSpec a;
    private SecretKeySpec b;
    private Cipher c;

    private native int getint();

    public native String I6MOYF();

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }

    public MC(String str) {
        this.a = new IvParameterSpec(str.getBytes());
        this.b = new SecretKeySpec((I6MOYF() + String.valueOf(getint())).getBytes(), "AES");
        try {
            this.c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public byte[] encrypt(String str) throws Exception {
        if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
            throw new Exception("Empty string");
        }
        try {
            this.c.init(1, this.b, this.a);
            return this.c.doFinal(a(str).getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("[encrypt] " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static String a(String str) {
        int length = 16 - (str.length() % 16);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            str = str + 0;
        }
        return str;
    }

    public byte[] des(String str) throws Exception {
        if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
            throw new Exception("Empty string");
        }
        try {
            this.c.init(2, this.b, this.a);
            Object doFinal = this.c.doFinal(hexToBytes(str));
            if (doFinal.length > 0) {
                int i = 0;
                for (int length = doFinal.length - 1; length >= 0; length--) {
                    if (doFinal[length] == (byte) 0) {
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                if (i > 0) {
                    Object obj = new byte[(doFinal.length - i)];
                    System.arraycopy(doFinal, 0, obj, 0, doFinal.length - i);
                    return obj;
                }
            }
            return doFinal;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("[decrypt] " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static byte[] hexToBytes(String str) {
        byte[] bArr = null;
        if (str != null && str.length() >= 2) {
            int length = str.length() / 2;
            bArr = new byte[length];
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                bArr[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i * 2, (i * 2) + 2), 16);
            }
        }
        return bArr;
    }
}
```

i understand that it uses OpenSSL "AES/CBC/NoPadding" mode for for decrypting the payload, however i am at loss how to take the payload and do it manually.

here is an example of the payload the server gives, the app send key header, however changing and dropping it does not change the payload, so i concluded it's not using the key for the actual encryption

```
AwFpdchYa7twLSEwN884uGQ/CNoLKrGBxtwIXGcL9OQTPPh96I1uhuh85HXLw3XUikVCmKaKgnssGorqYuvHQELce3nAhnaeHDcEsMFIykeitgDWLXeCed6f9UXHn+XF8nC3arHVbhMgIW8bUlWMq6KygRb4jeUufRHJzJ7LK0q6TvY+rF+utv3i//3NCuKfmbiiMlBvyDdMWPIL83YywkdjLujbBn0RNaeqUDjE0I7xqYypWPjwPXH1DZPbnGFYHemJgNS8QKtFnbtiRwEhpzx2sEoe/NBIgvcXsYkRSgrt+Q==
```

So the main question is, how would you use the provided code to manually decrypt the payload?

EDIT:

as suggested by Mr. @Robert, i tried to see how the native functions being called, so i installed `frida-server` on android emulator, and here is the interesting call, not sure what to make of it

```
/* TID 0x10b1 */
15066 ms  open(pathname="/data/app/com.friga.gameapp-lPtwMqeZ36x47-Yo8YDzOg==/lib/x86/libnative-lib.so", flags=0x0)
```

i guess this supposed to be the key? `-lPtwMqeZ36x47-Yo8YDzOg==`

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking for. Edit your question and add a concrete question.

Comment: @Robert, Thank you what i am asking is "how would you use the provided code to manually decrypt the payload outside the app itself?".

Comment: Please don't use comments edit your question instead. Also add what you have already tried. BTW: Do you have the key `I6MOYF` which comes from the native library?

Comment: I already accepted the suggested edit, and i also added the question, as i said i am still rookie when it's come to java and android, i assume this method is provided by java or android sdk?

Comment: All method with the keyword `native` are not available as Java code. In this case they are implemented in the `native-lib.so` (usually ARM code) which should be present in the APK file.

Comment: so here is what i understand so far, i should load the library within the class and try to decrypt using MC.des method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem using `frida` by following "[Frida hooking android part 5: Bypassing AES encryption](https://11x256.github.io/Frida-hooking-android-part-5/)" post by 11x256 blog